# Convergence of $\sum \limits _{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \frac{2^nn!}{5 \cdot 7 \cdot \ldots \cdot (2n+3)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$\sum \limits _{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \dfrac{2^nn!}{5 \cdot 7 \cdot \ldots \cdot (2n+3)}$

How to check this? I've tried using Leibniz test, it's easy to prove that this one is monotonous, but its limit is rather not $0$.

Comment: @Element118: The ratio test is only for series with positive terms; for alternating series there is the Leibniz test, that the OP claims to have already tried.

Comment: Check again, the limit is $0$.

Comment: By the way, the correct term is "monotonic" rather than "monotonous"

Comment: In general, $~S(x)~=~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+3)!!}\cdot x^{2n}~=~\frac1{x^2}\cdot\bigg[1-\frac{\arcsin x}x\cdot\sqrt{1-x^2}\bigg].~$ In this particular case, our series is $~3~S(i)-1~=~3\sqrt2~\ln(1+\sqrt2)-4.~$

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite each term into:

$$2\times\frac{4}{5}\times\frac{6}{7}\times\frac{8}{9}\times\frac{10}{11}\times\dots\times\frac{2n}{2n+1}\times\frac{1}{2n+3}<\frac{2}{2n+3}$$

Hence, the limit of the terms go to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

You had the right idea to try to use the alternating series test, however you should double check your calculations for the limit of the terms:

$\dfrac{2^n n!}{5 \cdot 7 \cdots (2n+3)}$ $= \dfrac{3 \cdot 2^nn!}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2n+3)}$ $= \dfrac{3 \cdot 2^nn!}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2n+3)} \cdot \dfrac{2^{n+2}(n+2)!}{2 \cdot 4 \cdots (2n+4)}$

$= \dfrac{3 \cdot 2^{2n+2}n!(n+2)!}{(2n+4)!}$ $= \dfrac{3 \cdot 2^{2n+2}(n+2)!^2}{(n+2)(n+1)(2n+4)!}$ $= \dfrac{3 \cdot 2^{2n+2}}{(n+2)(n+1)} \cdot \dbinom{2n+4}{n+2}^{-1}$

$\sim \dfrac{3 \cdot 2^{2n+2}}{(n+2)(n+1)} \cdot \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi(n+2)}}{2^{2n+4}}$ $=  \dfrac{\tfrac{3\sqrt{\pi}}{4}}{(n+1)\sqrt{n+2}} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$,

Then, by the alternating series test, the series converges.

In fact, the series converges absolutely, as we have shown that the terms behave like $n^{-3/2}$.

Answer (score 1):

For
$\sum \limits _{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \dfrac{2^nn!}{5 \cdot 7 \cdot \ldots \cdot (2n+3)}
$,
the ratio of consecutive terms is
$\dfrac{\dfrac{2^{n+1}(n+1)!}{5 \cdot 7 \cdot \ldots \cdot (2n+3)(2n+5)}}{\dfrac{2^nn!}{5 \cdot 7 \cdot \ldots \cdot (2n+3)}}
=\dfrac{2(n+1)}{(2n+5)}
=\dfrac{2n+2}{2n+5}
=1-\dfrac{3}{2n+5}
$

so that the terms decrease
in absolute value
and,
since
$\prod (1-\dfrac{3}{2n+5})
\to 0
$
(because
$\sum \dfrac{3}{2n+5}$
diverges,
the terms go to zero
so the series converges.